# in laravel 5.4 make:mail not exists

Tags: email, laravel-5

D:\xampp\htdocs\blog>php artisan make:mail Waleed

[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]

Command "make:mail" is not defined.

Did you mean one of these?

```
  make:model
  make:provider
  make:policy
  make:request
  make:seeder
  make:migration
  make:test
  make:middleware
  make:controller
  make:console
  make:event
  make:job
  make:listener
  make:auth
```

Comment: are you have guzzlehttp/guzzle in your composer.json?

Comment: thanks @OdinThunder I am using guzzle

Comment: Any update on this? I'm fairly new to Laravel and I'm also missing this make command. There's absolutely nothing on the interwebs on this, so that makes me believe I'm doing something wrong.